# Align the div to exact center to the main div

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I get the center div to exactly center to the parent div.
Here is my sample http://jsfiddle.net/sVPDS/11/

The middle image should come horizontally center to the main div.

Comment: if you don't have other thing specified margin: auto; should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you try applying this `css` instead of your previous style in the class `carousl`-

```
.carousl{
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

your previous and next buttons will need some extra padding or margin, hope you can take care of them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `float: left` style from `.carousl_img`

Answer (score 0):

you need a proper width say: width: 100%; on class 'carousl_img'.

EDIT:

You will also need a proper width on 'carousl'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it with js and it will be perfect. All you need to do is include this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[DIR_PATH]/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var PW = $('div.product_detail').width();
        var LM = (PW/2).toFixed(2);
        $("div.carousel").css('margin-left', LM+"px");      
    });
</script>
```

Do let me know if its solved